# h264 video does not play in Opera with Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: opera, mp4, 19.10

I can't watch h.264 video mp4 format in Opera browser. Ubuntu version 19.10.
It was working in 19.04.

Comment: I think the problem is due to the absence of h264 decoder. To solve it, just install the needed libraries mentioned in the link shared by @digiwizkid .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, to install Opera from snap was not necessary. Just install the chromium codecs from snap by:

```
sudo snap install chromium-ffmpeg
```

Then go to the created `/snap/chromium-ffmpeg` directory and search for the `libffmpeg.so` file (I just selected the folder with the higher number supposing is the newest, in my case `/snap/chromium-ffmpeg/15/chromium-ffmpeg-95241`).

Copy and replace the `libffmpeg.so` file to the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera directory`. That worked for me.

Comment: worked for me too (I can now uninstall google-chrome browser)

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by installing the Opera browser from the snap store, so it can use Chromium codecs. In 19.10 Chromium can only be installed by snap. I found this solution on the Opera forums.